# Has anyone got a Text to Speech engine installed?

Tags: software-development, software-recommendation, speech-synthesis

Just wondering whether anyone has got a Text to Speech engine installed on the Pi?It would make a great addition to almost any programming project to make it talk to the user!

Comment: The [MagPi 3rd Edition](http://goo.gl/CQgS4) with listing of games and apps mentions a `TextToSpeech` engine.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes it is possible; I saw a YouTube [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b7qc61UvZK4) of the Pi reading the news using [festival](http://www.cstr.ed.ac.uk/projects/festival/).

Use the following command to install festival using Debian

```
$ sudo apt-get install festival festival-freebsoft-utils
```

To make it speak simply pipe it the text or file you want it to read, like so

```
echo  "Hello World"| festival --tts
```

References:

1. http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=40548

Answer (score 11):

You could install espeak:

```
$ sudo apt-get install espeak # For Debian
$ sudo pacman -S espeak # For Arch Linux
```

To make it speak:

```
$ espeak "Hello World" # Replace Hello World with your text, must be enclosed by ""
$ espeak -f <file> # Read out file <file>
```

Answer (score 8):

[flite](http://packages.debian.org/wheezy/flite) is a cut-down version of festival which I have found to work very well on small ARM hosts.

Comment: Best option in my opinion, mainly because of it's focus on speed and few dependencies (it's also written in C!), +1.

Comment: English only, so eSpeak is still the winner for me...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you are looking for a premium solution, but Cepstral just released their Callie voice for use on the Raspberry Pi. You have to call them atm to get pricing info etc, but if you don't mind paying something, just wanted to put it out there as an option.

http://www.cepstral.com/en/raspberrypi

Answer (score 0):

Acapela works quite well on similar devices. Not free, though.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use googles API the drawback is that you need an internet connection but the result is probable the best you are going to get.