# Problem with eSpeak on Raspberry Pi 3B+ (TTS ~ Text-To-Speech)

Tags: raspbian, text-to-speech

Good evening, i have a problem with eSpeak engine. I have no problem with the robotic voice, but it's somehow low quality *(maybe 8Hz and Mono, i really don't know)*. Can i fix this? I work on Python with pyttsx3 library. I did google my question and nothing. Any tips?

Comment: This would live better on the general programming or Linux exchanges as its not Pi specific - I do know the multi-language version https://github.com/espeak-ng/espeak-ng/blob/master/src/espeak-ng.1.ronn supports pitch adjustment and multiple voices (https://github.com/espeak-ng/espeak-ng/tree/master/espeak-ng-data/voices/!v) - maybe that would be a starting point?  Voting closed I'm afraid.

Comment: (Blush) - voices are available directly - see answer two of https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/38467/project-text-to-speech-for-a-blind-parent?rq=1  pulling close(/Blush)

Comment: @Andyroo thanks! I was searching for something like this.